# Iterating scraped data to return as a field objects inside an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, embed, discord

I have a Discord bot that scrapes web data from inside an unordered list, the amount of list items in the ul can vary week by week from a minimum of 5 to a peak of 20.

I use this code to scrape the data (node.js and Cheerio):

```
$('li').eq(65).siblings().each(function(i, elem) {
                details[i] = $(this).text().replace(/\*/g, ' ').split('/').join('or').trim();
            });
```

My problem is because the number of list item elements can change on a weekly basis I never know how many addField objects to use when rendering the embed to Discord screen, so I can't add them by array index position as I would either have null values or not enough fields, I need  to be able to generate addField objects so that each of the array index's returned is inside its own addField.

The embed is rendered with this code:

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(0xf1c40f)
                    .setTitle('Listing For The Week:')
                    .addField('Items', `${details}`)
                    .setTimestamp();

                client.channels.get('546033223172620288').send({ embed });
```

This just displays the entire scraped data inside one field and it looks horrible as you can imagine, which is why I want to iterate the data into seperate .addFields.

I'm learning js so what do I have to do to get my desired outcome? I'm looking at doing something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
               .addField('ITEM:', details);
            }
```

but I don't have the knowledge how to work with the .addField object and keep getting errors and finding that google isn't helping me find out how to approach this with the dot notation on addField inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're one the right track I suppose. You can't simply have a "random" `.addField()` out there like that though. Simply utilize your existing `embed` variable within the loop - `embed.addField('ITEM', details)`

Comment: I was just coming to update my post with my solution.. you beat me to it :) What you answered is exactly what I did a few hours ago and solves the issue, Thank you.. I've marked you down as answering the question,